# Icarus Detect Failed

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-setup, raspberry-pi

I have been running raspberry PI with 4 Erupter modules connected to Pi Hub for 5 days with no problems. Yesterday I checked the modules and the idle lights were on and there was no mining. I restarted my raspberry, and now I am getting this error:

```
 [2014-04-10 20:23:13] Icarus Detect: Test failed at /dev/ttyUSB0: get 00000000,
 should: 000187a2
 [2014-04-10 20:23:13] Icarus Detect: Test failed at /dev/ttyUSB1: get 00000000,
 should: 000187a2
 [2014-04-10 20:23:14] Icarus Detect: Test failed at /dev/ttyUSB3: get 00000000,
 should: 000187a2
```

I am running the following command:

```
sudo ./cgminer-3.1.1/cgminer --config /home/pi/cgminer.conf -S /dev/ttyUSB0 -S /dev/ttyUSB1 -S /dev/ttyUSB2 -S /dev/ttyUSB3
```

If I connect and run the modules one by one there are no issues. When there are 3-4 I get errors. Those errors change each time I run it, so sometimes its 1 failing other times 2 etc. Also, I am getting this error:

```
[2014-04-10 20:33:04] Most likely you have input the wrong URL, forgotten to ad
d a port, or have not set up workers
```

Again, there have not been any changes to the configuration (that I am aware of). Any suggestions as to what might be causing this/ how to fix it?

**Update**

```
cgminer.conf 

"pools" : [
        {
                "url" : "http://api.bitcoin.cz:8332",
                "user" : "worker",
                "pass" : "pass"
        }
]
,
    "api-listen" : true,
    "api-port" : "4028",
    "expiry" : "120",
    "failover-only" : true,
    "log" : "5",
    "no-pool-disable" : true,
    "queue" : "2",
    "scan-time" : "60",
    "worktime" : true,
    "shares" : "0",
    "kernel-path" : "/usr/local/bin",
    "api-allow" : "0/0",
    "icarus-options" : "115200:1:1",
    "icarus-timing" : "3.0=100"
}
```

Erupters run from powered hub, and rpi is also running from wall charger.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a power problem to your erupters most likely. Can you show me the config file or the options you are enabling? In particular, the `-scan` option.

Further, you might verify you have a powered USB hub and try using a powered USB port if available; it only takes a little power to run them, but a little power to stop them. I also power my rasp pi through a wall charger also, rather than powering it from the usb hub.

I have had much more success running BFGMiner with Erupters and Antminer U1 USB sticks with a Pi and usb hub to control (and using Minepeon on the rasp pi). The command to start BFGMiner and scan for erupters etc and create a log in case you do have problems is:

`bfgminer –o [pool] –u [user] –p [password] –scan-serial erupter:all –icarus-options 115200:1:1 –icarus-timing 3.0=100 2>logfile.txt`

Comment: I have updated the question. I am not sure what you mean by -scan option, is it the -S? I will be trying bfgminer shortly.

Comment: Yes, -S is also scan, I just used the long form notation so you might understand what the options are for and what they do.

You can type the commands that I stated above in BFGMiner, or their abbreviation. Furthermore, I don't think it's necessary to add any options after the --scan (-S), because I think the mining software will automatically set the values once it detects it from scanning. Simply running  "bfgminer –o [pool] –u [user] –p [password] –scan-serial erupter:all" works for me, but you can also replace "all" with the device (Icarus, most likely) name and scan directly for it.